# Assigning a DateTime to a Date database column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'a
```

When I want get a DateTime

```
        var dat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        godz.date = dat;
```

godz.data is type `Date` in database.

How fix it?

Comment: Don't call `ToShortDateString()`, just use `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are trying to pass a `string` where a `datetime` is expected.  Try changing to this:

```
var dat = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about setting

```
godz.date = DateTime.Now;
```